# How to prevent scrolling multiple elements in React-Native ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm attempting to create a horizontal ScrollView that snaps to an interval. I only want it to scroll one item/element at a time, no matter how much force is applied to their swipe gesture.

I've tried using the available props on ScrollView, and it does what I want nearly perfectly, other than the fact that when more force or longer swipe is applied, multiple elements get scrolled through.

I made a snack on expo here: https://snack.expo.io/BkKzYHpbE

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView 
                style={styles.container}
                horizontal= {true}
                decelerationRate={0}
                snapToInterval={width - 60}
                snapToAlignment={"center"}
                contentInset={{
                    top: 0,
                    left: 30,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 30,
                }}>
                <View style={styles.view} />
                <View style={styles.view2} />
                <View style={styles.view} />
                <View style={styles.view2} />
                <View style={styles.view} />
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {},
    view: {
        marginTop: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width: width - 80,
        margin: 10,
        height: 200,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    view2: {
        marginTop: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: width - 80,
        margin: 10,
        height: 200,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
});
```

You can see a gentle, short swipe will scroll one element as expected. But a longer, more forceful swipe causes elements to be skipped, which is not what I'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'pagingEnabled' prop of scrollView. That will solve your problem.
Also remove `snapToAlignment` and `snapToInterval` props